# TeX Live on Windows 2016 cannot find pygmentize!

Tags: texlive, windows, minted

I have installed TexLive 2016 and Anaconda3 on a Windows Server 2016. When I open a DOS box and type

```
pygmentize
```

then the program is run. However, when I do

```
c:\local\texlive\2016\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe -shell-escape talk.tex
```

I get

```
(c:/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/font/beamerfontthemes
erif.sty) (/users/eda/mosekprj/generic/docs/branding/tex-common/msk-math.tex))system returned with code -1

\minted@apppathifexists=

! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.40 \begin{document}
```

Any suggestions for a solution or how to debug this?

Comment: What does `echo %PATH%` in the DOS box give? How _exactly_ are you running `pdflatex` (same DOS box, same directory or ...?).

Comment: I run the command in the directory in which the tex is located. And yes it is on the C drive.

Comment: pygmentize are on the PATH. And I run pdflatex from the DOS box in which I check pygmentize can be run.

Comment: I also tried to add the command \renewcommand{\MintedPygmentize}{c:/local/Anaconda3/Scripts/pygmentize.exe}. But nothing changed.

Answer (score 6):

The problem can be fixed by doing

```
set PATH=c:\windows\system32;%PATH%
```

this makes sure cmd.exe is available. My guess is pdflatex or minted requires cmd.exe.

I do know why cmd.exe is not on the PATH on a Windows 2016. Most likely for security reasons.

See also

http://erlingdandersen.blogspot.dk/2017/01/installing-texlive-2016-on-windows.html

which helped my guess the solution.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Seems unlikely: Win10 does have `%systemroot%\system32` in the standard path

Comment: Maybe. But the solution suggested did the trick.

Comment: @JosephWright something similar came up on texlive list the other day,  a recent windows update? http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2016-December/039514.html